# Lithium: find list with condition not in a array

Tags: mongodb, find, lithium

I am trying to use the find for a list having fields = name and the field "number" NOT in a list of array $importedVolumes.

```
$importedVolumes = array('22','38');

   Volumes::find('list', array(
    "fields"=>"name",
    "conditions"=>array("number"=> 
      array("NOT IN"=>$importedVolumes)
     ),
    "order"=>"number ASC"
  ));
```

The above gives a null array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using MongoDB, use `$nin` operator

```
'conditions' => array(
    'number' => array('$nin' => $importedVolumes)
 )
```